# BluImp Gallery allows image to be dragged vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

I am using the [blueImp image gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) in a carousel.
I am allowing images to be dragged for a mobile user, but images can be dragged vertically as well as horizontally, meaning you can get the image half dragged off screen.

As you drag, the .slide element changes inline to dimensions like:
`style="transform:translate(-100px, 256px)"`

I have tried setting a `translateY(0) !important` but this just overwrites the dragging altogether.

I am using jQuery, so maybe there is a way of watching the drag event? Any help useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way I managed to do it was to overwrite blueimp's ontouchmove function. You just need to comment out the translateY call. I took the source from https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/js/blueimp-gallery.js.

Place the whole overwite somewhere in your js, ideally separate file with comment for future.

```
blueimp.Gallery.prototype.ontouchmove = function (event) {
    ...
    } else {
        // Removed move up/down funictionality
        //this.translateY(index, this.touchDelta.y + this.positions[index], 0);
    }
};
```

Hope it helps you!
Maybe blueimp can add an option to toggle this behavious in future :)

Pav